# Scripting Microsoft Data Warehouse Wizard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, scripting, management-data-warehouse

I am trying to automate the MDW setup process in my environment. Currently I have everything complete except for enabling the data collectors (usually uses a wizard as seen [image: here]).

Has anyone seen or used a script for this? Or have any suggestions? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not my area of expertise, but you might look at Dennes Torres **Simple Talk** post from January 2015 for any takeaways that help you.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/centralize-your-database-monitoring-process/

Two subheadings of particular interest may be:

- Configure Data Collector through CMS
- Configure Collection Sets through CMS